# Update UIimageview of a UITableviewCell without reloading it

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have created a custom `UITableviewCell Subclass` which consists of many `UIImageViews`.
On click of any `UIImageView` Phone Camera Album is opened and after selecting any pic it returns me an UIImage in delegate method of `UIImagePickerController`.

Now all I want is to update that particular `UIImageView` image without reloading the Tableview or that particular indexPath.
I have made outlets of that `UIImageViews` in my TableViewCell Subclass.
How can I achieve it.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to set the image in the cell and not getting the update? Or don't you know how to set it in the first place?

Comment: I am getting reference from tableview visible cell property and then setting it.

Comment: But the image doesn't change? Where are you running into an issue?

Comment: I am not getting reference of that cell actually even though i have written it as `guard let tableviewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as? EditProfileTableviewCell else{return}`

Comment: Might be a stupid question but you are giving the correct section and row in NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0) right?

Does the code exit in the guards return?

Comment: yes actually it exits.I found a solution. After using dispatch_after with 0.1 sec delay I am getting the cell.Thanks BTW!!

Comment: It might be a bit easier if you showed your code from the UIImagePickerController delegate method